# Menu displayed on all pages, code is replicated in all controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

I have a collection model. I succesfully created a `_collection.html.erb` that i call with `<%= render @collections%>` in my application layout.

My problem is that in ALL my controlers method I must add `@collections = Collection.all`

I found it very very ugly,it will make my collection scope a pain to change, and I'm sure that I am missing a rails magic something that would be way nicer.

Is there a way to have a part of the layout generated by model data without having a identical piece of code in AAAALLLLLL the controllers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that your controllers all inherit from `ApplicationController`.  Use this to your advantage.  Add a `before_filter` to `ApplicationController` that loads your collections.

Comment: mmm, my rails project does not contain any file named ApplicationController. Do you mean i should create some kind of Application Controller class that would inherit the real ApplicationControllers rail class and allow before_filter method to be called by .... something ?

Comment: @Sylario: `ApplicationController` is in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` (following the usual rails convention)

Answer (score 1):

@cam was right. Any rails project has an ApplicationController. Your controllers all start with MyController < ApplicationController, right? If so, that means you can create a before_filter in your ApplicationController, which will be inherited by all your controllers. To do so :

```
/app/controllers/application_controller.rb

before_filter :load_collection

def load_collection
    @collections = Collection.all
end
```

From now on, you can use @collections from all your controllers (as long as they inherited from ApplicationController)